# Extracting Words using  Perl

Tags: perl

I like to extract the words from the text.  I have written the simple regex.

```
my $regex = qr[\W];
while(<DATA>){
    push  @words, split $regex;
}
```

I like to modify it to include proper names. Proper names may combine multiple 'words'. For example..

```
@names = ('John Smith', 'Joe Smith');
```

Comment: How does your input data look like?

Comment: Are you storing the exact list of "allowed" proper names? If not what are the exact rules for "proper names"

Comment: M42: Usually it is  book chapter(s) or  webpage(s).      DVK:Storing is my only option as I am not aware of rules. Upon further thinking, I can construct something like \b[A-Z][a-z]+[\s][A-Z][a-z]+\b  to begin with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there is a definitive solution. The regular expression is limited in a complex text space like a web page or book with many anomalies, e.g. what about book titles?  Look at using either 1) natural language processing or 2) An index approach where you identify two words, starting with capital letter, split by one space, and see if one of them is contained with an index of known first or last names. good luck.

Comment: depending on your interest in solving this, and other problems like it, may I suggest the stanford online course, http://www.nlp-class.org/

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps:

```
!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;
my @words;
while(<DATA>){
    push @words, $1 if m{([A-Z]\w*\s+[A-Z]\w*)};
}   
for my $name (@words) {
    print "$name\n";
}
print Dumper \@words;
__DATA__
John Smith I am
He is Joe Smith 
John Doe
Sam
Sally
Sally Girl
```

Comment: This approach is one regex, but it may not function for all cases.  I would rather go with the list approach.

Comment: A "list approach" suggests that you want to populate a hash with "valid" names; parse your input and do whatever if the name is valid.